# HTML / CSS Anchor Tag Style Specificity

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a project that has these requirements:

1. When hovering over a section with anchors, the colors of all anchors in that section (non hover/active state) change.
2. The active/hover state color of these anchors should inherit the normal anchor active/hover color.

I was able to achieve the first requirement, but the active/hover states don't change at all when hovering over the specific link.  It's obviously an issue with specificity, but I can't seem to figure out why.

Here is a boiled down version of the code:  http://codepen.io/dbough/pen/maxrv

```
a:link, a:visited {
  color:green;
}
a:hover, a:active, header .color a:hover, header .color a:active {
  color:pink;
}
.color a:link, .color a:visited{
  color:red;
}

$("header").hover(function() {
  $("header").addClass("color");
        },
        function() {
            $("header").removeClass("color");
        }
    )
```

Comment: what do you mean by active/hover, lil confusion though

Comment: @kirk The active/hover state of an anchor.  Not sure what the confusion is?  http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the simplest terms.

1. Define a color for all links
2. Set a hover color hased on the **ul** being hovered
3. Set a different colow when the a is hovered

   a:link {
     color:green;
   }

   ul:hover a {
      color:pink; 
   }

   ul a:hover {
     color:red;
   }

**[Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/Ejkof)**

Does that not meet the criteria(?)...and no JS required

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with specificity, your selector just doesn't match.

```
header .color a:active {
```

You are using JavaScript to add a class to the `<header>` element, but you are writing a selector where the element with the class is a descendant of the `<header>`.

Remove that descendant combinator from the selectors:

```
header.color a:active {
```

Answer (score -2):

delete your style and jquery hover function and try use this (only css):

```
html,body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
header {
  width:50%;
  padding:auto;
  margin:auto;
}
li {
  display:inline;
  padding:50px;
}

a, a:link, a:visited{
  color:green;
}
a:hover, a:active{
  color:pink !important;
}
header:hover a{color:red;}
```

Comment: I discourage people using !important.

Comment: sometime you must use this example when two style working together. This is that situation

Comment: @mcmac sometimes... Well more like almost never. But when it isn't neccesary don't use it. Remember that a more specific selector has more priority, thus no need for the `!important`. http://jsfiddle.net/Y4NKH/